# Creating graphical VM on Ubuntu Server but can't connect to VNC

Tags: networking, server, virtualization, 18.10, vnc

I am trying to create an Ubuntu Desktop 18.10 VM on my Ubuntu Server 18.10 so that I could remotely connect on the local network and eventually outside the local network.

```
$ sudo virt-install --virt-type=kvm --name ubuntu18 --ram 2048 --vcpus=2 --os-variant=ubuntu18.10 --hvm --cdrom=/var/lib/libvirt/boot/ubuntu-18.10-desktop-amd64.iso --network default --graphics=vnc,listen=0.0.0.0 --disk size=10
WARNING  Graphics requested but DISPLAY is not set. Not running virt-viewer.
WARNING  No console to launch for the guest, defaulting to --wait -1

Starting install...
Allocating 'ubuntu18.qcow2'
Domain installation still in progress. Waiting for installation to complete. 
        |  10 GB  00:00:02
```

This creates the qcow2 file. I've tried with both `--network default` and `--network=bridge=virbr0,model=virtio`.

```
$ virsh vncdisplay ubuntu18
:0
```

This should mean that I can connect via VNC at port 5902?

However, trying to use the ip of the server 192.168.0.x or the virbr0 interface ip 192.168.122.1 to connect with TightVNC I am unable to connect.

I believe this is a lack of understanding of networks and networking. How can I properly setup the VM such that I could connect with TightVNC on a machine from my local network? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I have feeling that you have virtual bridge configured to 192.168.122.1/24 and your lan is 192.168.0.1/24. If this is correct, your virbr0 interface is nat interface, and you need to make 1:1 nat or port forward to your virtual machine, to access it outside your lan subnet. I suggest bridged networking `--network bridge=BRIDGE`, explained in virt-install manual:

[virt-install manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/virt-install.1.html)